# Magento replacing sku with upc/ean in email templates

Tags: email, magento

I want to replace the sku in my email templates with upc but I've got no clue on how to fix that.
I've looked for how to remove sku but to no avail. Can anyone point me to the right direction.

All I know is that the SKU is wrapped around in this code;

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

but have yet to figure out how to replace the sku with upc/ean

Answer (score 0):

This page helped me out alot on how to find and replace the sku attributes etc

http://www.keyzo.co.uk/blog/magento-further-e-mail-customisation/